# Can a foreign key in a database reference more than one element?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to set up a database with Django / PostgreSQL, but I can't figure out if this is something I can do. What I would like to do in my table is to have various elements, each of them with their primary key field, but at the same time, in the same table, also have a column for each element which would have a foreign key constraint that references a list of primary keys of those elements. So it would have to look like this:

```
|_pk_|_x_|_y_|_dependencies_|
|pk1 |---|---|   [pk2,pk3]  |
|pk2 |---|---|--------------|
|pk3 |---|---|--------------|
```

What I don't understand is if it's possible to have the Foreign key column reference more than one primary key, because in Django if I just had to reference the same table I would simply say models.ForeignKey('self') and that would automatically reference the primary key of the same table, but I need this for more than one primary key (or even None, it really depends on the item).

Is this doable? Would it be better to just devise a way to have the same referencing but using more than one table?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you need a many-to-many relationship with self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference more than one field in a `ForeignKey` in Django.

Have you thought about using a `ManyToManyField`?

It creates a intermediate table that allows an arbitrary amount of references to and from this element.

If you don't want that you may also use a CSV-Field (or the new postgres-specific [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) from 1.8) but then have to do contraint validation yourself …

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use a ManytoMany field but in creating the intermediate table it also adds a row to the table for each reference I need, which would become a problem for me in no time, since I expect a lot of these references. Is there a way to force Django to group all the references to the same key in one row, maybe using an ArrayField or ListField?

Comment: Why would that become a problem quickly? I bet there's installations out there with milions of entries inside m2m tables that still work fine. But if there is no way around it you need to do the latter thing, self-validating contraints saved in an [Array Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

Comment: Intermediate table is not a problem as far as I can see. In relational database there's no way of having m2m relation without explicitly defining what IS the relation. That's why it's called relational database, right?

Comment: My fear is that, seeing as the main table will have ~500.000 entries to start with, the m2m table could quickly escalate to tens of millions of entries. But for now this approach is working, so thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is an example.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_t1_t2 FOREIGN KEY (refcol1, refcol2)
                    REFERENCES table2(col1, col2)
```